# If statement to check if the value of a variable is in a JSON file

Tags: python, json, tkinter

I'm kind of new so try not to judge me. I'm trying to create a little 2d game based on the old 2d Mario. I already have home window, the sign up and login windows, and I've got a json file to save the usernames and passwords. **Now, I'm trying to get the login function to work.**
The problem seems to be this line:

```py
if plpaword in players['password']
```

This should help you understand what the variables stand for

```py
f = open('player.json')
players = json.load(f)
plpaword = E2.get()
```

When I run my code, everything else seems to work fine until I try to log in. After logging in, it should create a new window, but what happens is nothing happens and it gives the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/kevin/PycharmProjects/ANewFile/ANewFile.py", line 101, in LI
    passwords = players['password']
KeyError: 'password'
```

I used these modules:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Frame, Entry, END
import random
import json
```

Creating an account and saving it to my player.json file:

```
    def SU():
        try:
            plusname = E1.get()
            plpaword = E2.get()
            plpaword2 = E3.get()
            plemail = E4.get()
            if plpaword == plpaword2:
                if plusname in players:
                    messagebox.showerror(random.choice(error), "An account with that username already exists. "
                                                               "Please choose another.")
                else:
                    players[plusname] = {'password': plpaword, 'email': plemail}
                    with open('player.json', 'w') as f:
                        json.dump(players, f)
                    signup.destroy()
                    messagebox.showinfo("Account Created!", "Please log in to your new account through log in.")
            else:
                messagebox.showerror(random.choice(error), "Passwords did not match. Please try again")
        except:
            messagebox.showerror(random.choice(error), random.choice(errormsg))
```

Comment: Please provide an example of `player.json` file too.

Comment: Without seeing what `player.json` has in it, I doubt we can help.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: That particular error seems to be because the key `password` doesn't exist in the `players` dictionary, and you're attempting to access it in your line `if plpaword in players['password']`. The classic way to handle this is to wrap the attempt in a `try/except`, but the Dictionary object also has a [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method that will handle it more concisely and allow you to set a default value that's iterable.
Disclaimer: I haven't worked in Python the last few years so there may be better ways

Comment: The first thing you should do to debug this is examine what `players` is immediately before you do the check. It's probably not what you're assuming it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code of `SU()`, the content inside the JSON file (also the content of `players`) should be something like below:

```json
{
  "user1": {"password": "pass1", "email": "user1@email.com"},
  "user2": {"password": "pass2", "email": "user2@email.com"}
}
```

So the checking should be:

```
plusname = E1.get()
plpaword = E2.get()
for player in players:
    if plusname == player and plpaword == players[plusname]["password"]:
        print("login successful")
        break
else:
    print("login failed")
```

That is `players["password"]` should be `players[plusname]["password"]` instead.

Comment: I reached out to a friend and got a similar answer. Thanks for using your time to answer my question anyway.